# Como restringir o cadastro de HQs para que cada HQ apareça apenas na coleção à qual está vinculada?

Tags: java, android-studio, sqlite

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo de controle de coleções de HQs que possui duas tabelas principais (Coleção e HQ). Para cadastrar uma nova HQ, é obrigatório associá-la a uma coleção já cadastrada. Gostaria de implementar a funcionalidade em que, ao cadastrar uma nova HQ dentro de uma coleção específica, apenas as HQs vinculadas àquela coleção sejam exibidas na lista da coleção. Como posso realizar essa restrição para garantir que cada HQ apareça apenas na coleção à qual ela está vinculada?

Link para o github com o código do projeto: https://github.com/fwckalex/ProjetoHQS

Comment: Boas-vindas. Perguntas não podem depender de links externos (como repositórios), a pergunta é uma duplicata, para continuar ou comentar faça na [pergunta original](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/587911/3635) e para reabrir a original siga as orientações que já lhe foram passadas. *Agradecemos a compreensão*.